# How to reduce app size for Play console when I have 850 png files in the drawable?

Tags: android, console, google-play-services

Bare with as this is my first ever question.

I'm developing an Android application and I was ready for it to be reviewed by Google and uploaded to the Playstore. It's a simple book reading application which uses individual .png files as the pages to scroll between and I use a ViewPager to view them. I was unaware that Google had a limit on the app size that you can upload at 150mb. [This is the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgkkT.png)

The original size of my drawables folder was 761mb. I have been able to convert it down significantly to 250mb however it is still 102mb over the limit. Minify is enabled. I have tried the Webp convert in Android Studio but it barely makes a difference. Using AAB also create more than a 10mb difference. [Click for APK Aalyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAYwQ.png).

Anyone know anything else I can do? I've tried to convert over the images again but it doesn't make any difference to the size. I would want the images to be saved on the device rather than downloaded from the internet so that it can be viewed offline. I have looked into expansion apk's but all of the documentation points towards it only being saved in external storage.

Comment: Also see: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery , specifically an `install-time` asset pack.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions:

1. If you do not want to receive images from the server, try to reduce the size of your photos(compress) with the following two sites:
   https://tinypng.com, https://tinyjpg.com
2. Convert your images to webp (in android studio right click on drawable image and click convert to webp)
3. **Recommended** use https://appicon.co/#image-sets to Get different sizes of your images ( mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi , xxxhdpi )